# How to write docker output to stdout/stderr as daemon

Tags: docker

So we can run a docker container as a daemon:

```
docker run -d --name foo foo
```

and then read the logs:

```
docker logs -f foo
```

but I am wondering how to only write to stdout/stderr, so that I can send the logs to splunk or cloudwatch etc. Something like:

```
(
  docker run --name foo foo &|  capture_logs
) & disown
```

what is the official way to do this?

Comment: because if we simply write to a local file, the local fs will fill up, eventually

Comment: You don't send logs to stdout, you select and configure a logging driver.

Comment: ok thanks, how does that work, do you have a link maybe?

Comment: You weren't specific to where you actually want to log (you only gave examples). But you can search the Internet for `docker logging driver` and wherever you actually intend to log.

Comment: I don't understand - I want to log to stdout/stderr, but also run the docker container as a daemon, I gave that example of using `disown` and the question was if there is a better or more official way to do it. if a docker logging driver is the way to do it, please add an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging options as @Michael pointed out and as described in the following [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

Generally speaking there are at least two ways to do it which will be discussed briefly below.

1. Using `splunk` driver as shown in [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/).

Start by creating an event collector token as described in the [docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.0/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector). The token will be used within splunk driver configuration.

docker cli example

```sh
docker run -d \
           --log-driver=splunk \
           --log-opt splunk-token=176FCEBF-4CF5-4EDF-91BC-703796522D20 \
           --log-opt splunk-url=https://splunkhost:8088 \
           --log-opt tag=foo-logs \
           --name foo foo
```

docker-compose example

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  foo_app:
  ...
  logging:
    driver: splunk
    options:
      tag: foo-logs
      splunk-token: 176FCEBF-4CF5-4EDF-91BC-703796522D20
      splunk-url: https://splunkhost:8088
  ...
```

2. Using `syslog` driver as shown in [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/).

docker cli example:

```sh
docker run \
      -–log-driver syslog –-log-opt tag=foo-logs \
      --name foo foo
```

docker-compose example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  foo_app:
  ...
  logging:
    driver: syslog
    options:
      tag: foo-logs
  ...
```

This will send all container logs to local syslog, you can take it from there and forward these to external udp port where splunk is ready to receive your logs.

So lets say that the Splunk server will receive the logs on port `514` then you need to add this to `rsyslogd` configuration and then restart rsyslogd service

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/20-splunk.conf
:syslogtag, contains, "foo-logs" @splunk_url:514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

Alternatively, if you intend to make it global for all containers then you can configure the logging through the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file itself like below (and don't forget to restart the docker service):

In case of `syslog`

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog"
}
```

In case of `splunk`

```
{
  "log-driver": "splunk",
  "log-opts": {
    "splunk-token": "176FCEBF-4CF5-4EDF-91BC-703796522D20",
    "splunk-url": "https://splunkhost:8088",
    ...
  }
}
```

Checkout the list of [supported logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)